# Wildcard path in circe's JSON traversal

Tags: json, scala, circe

Consider this JSON:

```
{
  "myDocument": {
    "variableName": {
            "attr1": "val1",
            "attr2": "val2"
        }
  }
}
```

I want to process JSON documents that will have some parts in common. Specifically, I want to extract that "common" parts and I want to use circe for that case.
I was taking a look at JSON traversal guide and [optics](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html) because I'll deal with deeply nested structures.

In the previous example, there is an attribute that holds an object. The documents that I'm going to parse will have `variableName` attribute with different names, so I can't do something like this:

`root.myDocument.variableName.attr1`

Is there a way in where I can specify some sort of wildcard? Something like this:

`root.myDocument.*.attr1`

I can't control all the possible name combinations present in that attribute but I certainly know that the attribute will be present in every document in that exact position. Consider `myDocument` as a fixed attribute and `variableName` as a fixed attribute with a different name in each document.

I can't find any information about this. Is it possible to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that, for each `myDocument`, there will be an element as first child, but you don't know the name of it (but you are sure of the position)? And for each first child, you want to be able to extract "attr1" and "attr2", am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @mdm That's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that the first child of `myDocument` is the variable element, and that you  want only the `attr1` and `attr2` children of `myDocument`s first children, you can do the following:

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe._
import io.circe.jawn._

val in2 =
  """
    |[
    |   {
    |     "myDocument": {
    |       "firstUnknown": {
    |               "attr1": "val1",
    |               "ignored": "not_important",
    |               "attr2": "val2"
    |           }
    |     }
    |   },
    |   {
    |     "myDocument": {
    |       "secondUnknown": {
    |               "also_ignored": "not_important",
    |               "attr1": "val3",
    |               "attr2": "val4"
    |           }
    |     }
    |   },
    |   {
    |     "myDocument": {
    |       "thirdUnknown": {
    |               "attr1": "val5",
    |               "ignored2": "not_important",
    |               "attr2": "val6",
    |               "again_ignored": "not_important"
    |           }
    |     }
    |   }
    |]
  """.stripMargin

case class MyDocument(attr1 : String, attr2 : String)
object MyDocument{
  implicit val decoder : Decoder[MyDocument] = Decoder.instance{hCursor =>
    val firstChildKey = hCursor.downField("myDocument").keys.flatMap(_.headOption)

    firstChildKey.map{key =>
      for{
        attr1 <- hCursor.downField("myDocument").downField(key).downField("attr1").as[String]
        attr2 <- hCursor.downField("myDocument").downField(key).downField("attr2").as[String]
      } yield MyDocument(attr1,attr2)
    }.getOrElse(Left(DecodingFailure("Element is not a Json object or it's empty.",List())))
  }
}

val docs = parse(in2).flatMap(_.as[Vector[MyDocument]])
```

The idea being that, once we move the cursor to a `myDocument` element, we get all the `keys` contained by the json object, take the first one (which will be the key of the variable element we are interested in), and then use that to move the cursor to the desired position to read `attr1` and `attr2`.

The result of the last line would be:

```
Right(Vector(MyDocument(val1,val2), MyDocument(val3,val4), MyDocument(val5,val6)))
```